# How to iterate through all the objects within an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, object, for-loop

I have a javascript function that passes an object that contains multiple other objects, e.g.

```
createButtons({ 
    normalButtons: {
        button: {
            type: 'website',
            name: 'Website',
        }
    }
    socialButtons: {
        socialButton: {
            type: 'fb-share',
            name: 'Share on Facebook'
        },
        socialButton: {
            type: 'copyUrl',
            name: 'Copy Link'
        }
    }
});
```

Now i want to iterate through all the socialButtons, but when I do using a for ... in loop, it only seems to get the first item

```
function createButtons(options) {
    for (x in options.socialButtons) {
        console.log(options.socialButtons[x]);
    }
}
```

It only logs 1 object, the Facebook one.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to solve this, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: You have duplicate keys. `socialButton` occurs two times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are successfully looping over the properties of that object. The problem is that you only have one property.

You defined a value for `socialButton` and then you defined another value for `socialButton`.

You need to make your property names unique.

Better yet: use an array.

Comment: If I create an array for each socialButton, what would that change regarding iterating through the array and getting for instance the 'type' of each socialButton?

Comment: "If I create an array for each socialButton" — Don't. Create **an** array containing *all* the socialButtons.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was being a bit too fast, but that's what I meant

Comment: You'd replace `for (x in options.socialButtons) {` with a standard for (var = 0; etc loop or a call to `your_array.forEach`.

Answer (score 2):

Your object will not gonna work as both of the items in socialButtons: have this same keys, so, the first button will be replaced with second.

I recommend changing second socialButton to socialButton2 and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using same property name `socialButton` inside `socialButtons` object. This is the cause of your problem.

Changing the name name `socialButton` to an unique property name will help you achieving what you want.